# How do I force a specific version (not the latest) of docker-compose?

Tags: docker, macos, docker-compose

I have to work on a project that require the version ˆ1.29.2 of docker-compose. How do I do that on MacOS?

Already uninstalled docker-compose. but I've found now way to put other than the latest version of docker-compose.

Comment: You can install the Docker Desktop solution on your Mac, this comes with Docker compose preconfigured.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the only way is to install a version of Docker Desktop that includes the required verison of docker-compose. Releases here: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/release-notes/

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the only way is to install a version of Docker Desktop that includes the required version of docker-compose.

Different releases can be downloaded here: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/release-notes

Answer (score -3):

[image: Docker]

You can install the Docker Desktop solution on your Mac, this comes with Docker compose preconfigured.